# Cannot remove qtspim from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, qt

I recently tried to install spim(mips compiler) on my machine and it didn't work. Now I'm trying to remove the whole thing but I simply cannot do it and the worse part is that every time I try to install a new, completely different package, I get the same error. I am really freaking out about having broken my machine(although it still works). Here's what I initially did:

```
sudo apt-get install spim
sudo apt-get install qt-sdk
```

Then I downloaded the.deb file from the following link and copied the folders in my usr folder. I also ran the debian file from terminal using the dpkg command.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/spimsimulator/files/

I tried to remove the qt-sdk using the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove qt-sdk
```

The error below was given when I tried to remove qt-sdk but it sitll shows up every time I try to install any other package or remove the spim itself:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-twitter account-plugin-windows-live appmenu-qt appmenu-qt5
  apturl-common ax25-node bamfdaemon cmake cmake-data consolekit
  dbconfig-common default-jdk docbook-xml docbook-xsl evolution-common friends
  friends-dispatcher friends-facebook friends-twitter gir1.2-accounts-1.0
  gir1.2-ebook-1.2 gir1.2-ebookcontacts-1.2 gir1.2-edataserver-1.2
  gir1.2-messagingmenu-1.0 gir1.2-signon-1.0 gnome-calculator
  gnome-system-monitor guile-2.0-libs gyp icoutils indicator-appmenu kate-data
  katepart kde-l10n-engb kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kdelibs-bin
  kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdoctools kubuntu-debug-installer
  kwalletmanager laptop-detect libaio1 libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386
  libatspi2.0-0:i386 libattica0.4 libax25 libbaloocore4 libbaloofiles4
  libbalooxapian4 libbamf3-2 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbotan-1.10-0
  libc-ares-dev libc-ares2 libck-connector0 libcolord1:i386
  libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:i386 libdevmapper1.02.1:i386 libdlrestrictions1 libepub0
  libevent-2.0-5 libevolution libfriends0 libgc1c2 libglew1.10 libglewmx1.10
  libgtk-3-0:i386 libgtkhtml-4.0-0 libgtkhtml-4.0-common
  libgtkhtml-editor-4.0-0 libice-dev libidl-common libidl0 libjs-codemirror
  libjs-jquery-cookie libjs-jquery-event-drag libjs-jquery-metadata
  libjs-jquery-mousewheel libjs-jquery-tablesorter libjs-jquery-ui
  libjs-node-uuid libjs-underscore libkactivities-bin libkactivities-models1
  libkactivities6 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4
  libkdeclarative5 libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4
  libkemoticons4 libkfile4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkio5 libkjsapi4
  libkjsembed4 libkmediaplayer4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4
  libkparts4 libkpty4 libkrosscore4 libktexteditor4 libkubuntu0
  libkxmlrpcclient4 liblcms2-2:i386 libmail-spf-perl libmcrypt4
  libmetacity-private0a libmkv0 libmodemmanagerqt1 libnatpmp1 libnepomuk4
  libnepomukcleaner4 libnepomukcore4abi1 libnepomukquery4a libnepomukutils4
  libnetaddr-ip-perl libnetworkmanagerqt1 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0
  libnux-4.0-0 libnux-4.0-common liboath0 libopenconnect2 liborbit-2-0
  liborbit2 libpam-ck-connector libphonon-dev libphonon4 libplasma3
  libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpoppler-qt4-4 libpst4 libpython2.7:i386
  libpython2.7-minimal:i386 libpython2.7-stdlib:i386 libqapt2 libqapt2-runtime
  libqca2 libqjson0 libqmobipocket1 libqt5clucene5 libqt5declarative5
  libqt5designer5 libqt5designercomponents5 libqt5help5 libqt5quickparticles5
  libqt5quicktest5 libqt5script5 libreoffice-gtk libsm-dev libsolid4
  libsoprano4 libssl-dev libssl-doc libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0
  libsys-hostname-long-perl libthreadweaver4 libunity-core-6.0-9
  libunity-gtk2-parser0 libunity-gtk3-parser0 libunity-misc4 libupstart1
  libv8-3.14-dev libv8-3.14.5 libvirtodbc0 libwayland-client0:i386
  libwayland-cursor0:i386 libwnck-common libwnck22 libxkbcommon0:i386
  libxt-dev libytnef0 libzip2 metacity-common mysql-server-core-5.5
  nepomuk-core-data nepomuk-core-runtime ntrack-module-libnl-0 nux-tools
  oneconf oneconf-common openbsd-inetd openjdk-7-jdk oxygen-icon-theme phonon
  phonon-backend-gstreamer phonon-backend-gstreamer-common
  phonon-backend-gstreamer1.0 plasma-scriptengine-javascript python-debtagshw
  python-gconf python-oneconf python-piston-mini-client python3-crypto
  python3-feedparser python3-httplib2 python3-oauthlib python3-oneconf
  python3-piston-mini-client qapt-batch qmlscene qtcreator qtcreator-doc
  qtcreator-plugin-cmake qtcreator-plugin-qnx qtcreator-plugin-remotelinux
  qtcreator-plugin-valgrind qtdeclarative5-controls-plugin qtdeclarative5-dev
  qtdeclarative5-quicklayouts-plugin re2c sa-compile sgml-data
  shared-desktop-ontologies software-center-aptdaemon-plugins soprano-daemon
  spamassassin spamc telepathy-indicator transmission-common ttf-dejavu-core
  ubuntu-extras-keyring unity-gtk-module-common unity-gtk2-module
  unity-gtk3-module unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files
  unity-lens-friends unity-lens-music unity-lens-photos unity-lens-video
  unity-scope-audacious unity-scope-calculator unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks
  unity-scope-clementine unity-scope-colourlovers unity-scope-devhelp
  unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks unity-scope-gdrive unity-scope-gmusicbrowser
  unity-scope-gourmet unity-scope-guayadeque unity-scope-home
  unity-scope-manpages unity-scope-musicstores unity-scope-musique
  unity-scope-openclipart unity-scope-texdoc unity-scope-tomboy
  unity-scope-video-remote unity-scope-yelp unity-scope-zotero
  unity-scopes-master-default unity-scopes-runner unity-services
  virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  qt-sdk
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 32,8 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 393716 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing qt-sdk (2ubuntu3) ...
Setting up qtspim (9.1.16) ...
QSqlDatabase: QSQLITE driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: 
Error reading collection file '/home/sabir/.local/share/QtProject/Assistant/qthelpcollection_5.5.0.qhc': Cannot load sqlite database driver..
dpkg: error processing package qtspim (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qtspim
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Edit:
I tried Ravan's answer and the problem still persists:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  spim*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 365735 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing spim (8.0+dfsg-6) ...
Purging configuration files for spim (8.0+dfsg-6) ...
Setting up qtspim (9.1.16) ...
QSqlDatabase: QSQLITE driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: 
Error reading collection file '/home/sabir/.local/share/QtProject/Assistant/qthelpcollection_5.5.0.qhc': Cannot load sqlite database driver..
dpkg: error processing package qtspim (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qtspim
```

Edit 2:
apt-cache policy

```
spim:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.0+dfsg-6
  Version table:
     8.0+dfsg-6 0
        500 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
     8.0+dfsg-5.1 0
        500 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe amd64 Packages
```

Edit 3:
apt-cache policy qt-sdk

```
qt-sdk:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2ubuntu3
  Version table:
     2ubuntu3 0
        500 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: edit your question and add what is output of `apt-cache policy spim`

Comment: @Ravan Added the output

Comment: `apt-cache policy qt-sdk` output please!

Comment: @Ravan added it

Comment: try this `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `qtspim` was not successfully installed. 
As long as the package is listed as a defective package, you can not do anything.

Therefore remove it via

```
sudo apt-get purge qtspim
```

After that

```
sudo apt-get remove qt-sdk
```

---

And you should start a

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

as you have a lot of unnecessary packages installed. ***;)***

Comment: This one worked perfect. Thanks a lot. That was a real headache considering I'm new to Ubuntu. I went out of my way to remove individual files as well and it didn't work. This did :D

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the sqlite driver with:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5sql5-sqlite
```

Then run again the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove qt-sdk
```

If it does not work it's probably due to your Qt version as I can see 5.5 in the the error logs:

```
/home/sabir/.local/share/QtProject/Assistant/qthelpcollection_5.5.0.qhc
```

Try to rename this file:

```
mv /home/sabir/.local/share/QtProject/Assistant/qthelpcollection_5.5.0.qhc /home/sabir/.local/share/QtProject/Assistant/qthelpcollection_5.5.0.qhc.bak
```

And again re-rerun the apt-get remove command.